# Comparing two columns if

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

Column A: `333 Ich wünschte, ich könnte 888 in meine Kindheit zurückkehren.`

Column B: `Ich wünschte, ich könnte in meine Kindheit zurückkehren.`

I have these two sentences in two columns. Now I want to compare them but without taking 333 and 888 into account. Without also the need to create a third column and replacing 333, because if I make any changes in the future in Column B is would see immediately if it were not to match in column A. 333 are actually tags but they won't show here so I replaced them with 333 for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[0-9]+", ))=B1
```

[image: 0]

and ArrayFormula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "[0-9]+", ))=B1:B)
```

---

or like this with color green, if both columns match:

```
=(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE($A1, "[0-9]+", ))=$B1)*(A1<>"")
```

[image: 0]